# JavaScript events propagation from Child objects

Tags: javascript, events

```
var parent = (function() {
    // private vars .....
    // private methods....

    var childObj = new Child()

    return {
        public: publicmethods,
        on: on
    };
}());


function Child() {
    var events;
};

Child.prototype.on(ev, fn) {
}
```

Unclear on how to bubble up events from child objects all the way up in an efficient way. Consider a library that provides an namespaced interface to the higher level application. Application can register for all the events. How can the parent object catch the events from child objects (multiple) and propagate/bubble them up to the application?

One obvious way is that each child object provides an interface to the parent object to register for events and then whenever the particular Child event fires, then parent must bubble it up. But I think this unnecessarily involves a lot of redundant code since this will need to be done for each of the Child objects. That is each different kind of Child object will have to duplicate the code for observer (pub-sub) pattern for registration of events and triggering of the events. As the parent starts to create multiple type of objects (Child1, Child2, Child3 etc), this will become unmanageable.

Is there a better way to manage this? using some sort of pattern for event delegation or bubbling. Most of the existing docs talk about event delegation in the DOM space. However as stated earlier, this is not related to DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Taking DOM as a reference for designing the event system you describe, propagation and bubbling works because all elements inherit a common base type that implements and participates in the process.

Each event is propagated from the top most parent through all descendants along the path till it reaches the target element, passing a context object along the way. This object is used to pass event details to the handlers as well as notify the propagation system that it should stop propagating.